# Existence of square or cubic root in following finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

If we write F16 the finite field with 16 Elements as $F_2[x]/(Q(x))$ with $Q(x)=x^4+x+1$ in $F_2[x]$ irreducible of degree 4 and let a and b be the equivalence classes of x and $x^4+x^3+x^2$ in the above representation of $F_{16}$. Do a and b have a quadratic or cubic root in $F_{16}$?

Answer (score 1):

In $F_{16}$, the multiplicative group has order $15=3\cdot 5$ showing what kind of roots of unity may exist (certainly no 2nd roots of unity).

In view of $x$, we have $x^2,x^3,x^4=x+1$, $x^5=x^2+x$, and so on with $x^{15}=1$ giving a 15th root of unity.

For your second element, $x^4+x^3+x^2 = x^3+x^2+x+1$ is a 5th root of unity as it divides $x^5+1$.

Comment: thank you for the answer. "multiplicative group has order 15=3⋅5 showing what kind of roots of unity may exist" is there any theorem about this, would really need to get a better understanding. Could you please also explain to me the last part a bit more thoroughly. Would be very thankful since there are a lot of gaps from my side.

Comment: I think the OP is asking for square and cubic root for the specific elements and not of $1$.